# Java - Draw background issue

Tags: java, background, paint

I want to draw my background image in the middle of the frame. As my image is not as big as the window, I want to put a black background.

Here is the code I use:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    if(this.background != null)
    {
        int bounds_top = getHeight() / 2;
        int bounds_left = getWidth() / 2;
        int half_height = this.background.getHeight(null) / 2;
        int half_width = this.background.getWidth(null) / 2;
        g.drawImage(this.background, bounds_left - half_width, bounds_top - half_height, this.background.getWidth(null), this.background.getHeight(null), this);

        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        //this.setOpaque(false);
    }
}
```

If I set the frame to be opaqe, my image is displayed but the background is gray.
If I set opaque to false, my frame is just black, no image is displayed.

So here is my question, how can I display my image and have a back background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a litle trick to solve it:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()));
g.drawImage(this.background, bounds_left - half_width, bounds_top - half_height, this.background.getWidth(null), this.background.getHeight(null), this);
```

This works well.

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing this in a JPanel child, call `setBackground(Color.black);` in the constructor, and implement the code in `paintComponent` first calling `super.paintComponent(g);` for the black background.

Answer (score 1):

You are drawing the image to the background, and then setting the background color to black.  Try setting the background color to black first, and then draw the image to it.  Otherwise it looks like you are drawing black over the image.

Comment: I tried putting the setBackground before drawImage but it gives me the same result as before